Is it safe to use Uhu 2-part epoxy glue to fix a broken cup handle?
I glued some ceramic cup holders that were delivered broken using Uhu epoxy glue. This glue is supposed to be good for temperatures of up to 100º C, but I wonder about the safety concerns if I use these cups to drink from them (even when excluding hot beverages). I was not able to find any details in this regard on the safety sheets, so any help is appreciated. The glue was applied only to the holder (no internal surface) and I dropped some residue near the points of contact.
Thanks!

"waterproof" doesn't always mean submersible, so bear in mind soaking or using a dishwasher might directly degrade the bond; also, ceramic is porous so moisture wicked from e.g. unglazed areas on the bottom of the mug might undermine the bond.

My biggest worry is that if the glue joint isn't very good, you'll get a lapful of hot coffee, and that hurts.
The components of epoxy are a bit toxic, but the chemical reaction renders it much safer; many epoxies are even ok for food contact once fully cured

I agree. Epoxy invariably degrades with heat, and ceramics are notoriously difficult to glue because they distort slightly when breaking with the result that they can rarely be abutted perfectly.

Thanks for the comments. I'll be careful not to put hot beverages in!

As long as it's only the cup handle you glued, and the epoxy cured completely hard (no stickiness left), epoxy is very safe.
However, if you glued the actual cup and beverages come into contact with the epoxy, I wouldn't consider it "food safe" unless the packaging explicitly says so. It's true that epoxy, once cured, is chemically extremely stable and usually doesn't give off any harmful chemicals. But it's still remarkably porous and liquids can seep into the cured epoxy and seep out again into your next cup of tea. Many people experienced this porous property of their very expensive epoxy kitchen counter tops when they got mustard or ketchup stains that seeped into the epoxy and won't come off anymore.

Thanks! The epoxy is completely outside of the area of contact with the liquid, so it should be fine. I'll be careful with it though!
